# Add Session Management to ASPX pages with Minimum Code Changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, session-state

I have an ASP .NET application which has a number of aspx pages. These pages were not having any login or session management features and any user could directly type the url and visit any page. 
Now I want to add state management feature to all the pages. I created a new signup and a basic login page which accepts username and password and has necessary database for it. It is fine to use any server or client state management features, but how can I implement it with very minimum code changes.

One straight forward solution here is to implement session variable in server side to store logged in user details and check for it in the Page_Load event handler of each and every page. But here, code change has to be made in all the pages and I don't want that as there are so many pages. Any easier way will help.
Any ideas please??

Comment: I guess, once you have the sign up/login page, update your config file to use "Forms Authentication" and point the Url to the login page, also disable anonymous access. I don't think you need to do any other code change.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all it was good that you haven't implemented authentication in Page_Load on every page. Whenever approach you think of requires that you copy-paste code in multiple places - you are doing something wrong.

That being said, you will probably need to create base class for your Pages and by doing that you could have authentication restricted to one spot / class.

However, it would be better if you combine that with what ASP.NET framework offers. From stuff you are talking about it seems you are using ASP.NET Forms - here is article that should provide you with fine overview on everything you need to do:

1. How to modify web.config to use Forms authentication
2. Login and Logout user (create authentication cookie)
3. Necessary code for authenticating requests that needs to be added to Global.asx
4. Restricting access to pages by entering appropriate values in web.config (although better approach would be with base class I mentioned)

[Role-based Security with Forms Authentication](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2905/Role-based-Security-with-Forms-Authentication)

Comment: This is in essence correct, the question is about authentication which does not require sessions. However, point 3 can be skipped since forms-authentication is already doing authentication on every request, and I'm wondering why point 4 claims that a base-class would be better. Any arguments for the later?